# how to use another file inside a php class

Tags: php, sql, database

I've got two files dbconnect.php and config.php

dbconnect.php

```
 <?php 
class connect{
    public function __construct(){
        $config = require_once __DIR__ . 'config.php';
    }

    private $dbhost = $config['host'];
    private $dbuser = $config['username'];
    private $dbpass = $config['pass'];
    private $dbname = $config['dbname'];

    public function startConn(){
        $this->DBcon = null;
        try{
            $this->DBcon = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->dbhost.";dbname=".$this->dbname, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo "error connecting:";
        }
        return $this->DBcon;
    }
}
```

?>

config.php

```
<?php

  /**
   * Contains all configurations
   *
  */
  return [
    'dbname' => 'user',
    'pass' => '@user.intern1',
    'username' => 'user1',
    'host' => 'localhost',
  ];
?>
```

in my dbconnect.php file;
how do I include variables from my config.php into the class connect

If I do it the following way above;
it yells at me and gives me Fatal error:
    "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$config' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\hngfun\profile\adeojoemmanuel\php-handler\dbconfig.php on line 8"

Comment: The most important isn't shown that is the code of `dbconfig.php`

Comment: Declared properties like `private $dbhost` cannot be assigned values that are dependent on runtime data, such as `$config['host'];`

Comment: where is file `dbconfig.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a guess here. But I can clearly see that you are setting $config as a local variable in the constructor. That means it is not available once you leave the constructor.

```
<?php 
class connect{
    public function __construct(){
        $config = require_once __DIR__ . 'config.php';
        $this->dbhost = $config['host'];
        $this->dbuser = $config['username'];
        $this->dbpass = $config['pass'];
        $this->dbname = $config['dbname'];
    }

    private $dbhost ;
    private $dbuser ;
    private $dbpass ;
    private $dbname ;

    public function startConn(){
        $this->DBcon = null;
        try{
            $this->DBcon = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->dbhost.";dbname=".$this->dbname, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo "error connecting:";
        }
        return $this->DBcon;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declared properties like `private $dbhost` cannot be assigned values that are dependent on runtime data, such as `$config['host'];`

Quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

The solution, assign the values in your constructor:

```
class connect{
    public function __construct(){
        $config = require_once __DIR__ . 'config.php';

        private $this->dbhost = $config['host'];
        private $this->dbuser = $config['username'];
        private $this->dbpass = $config['pass'];
        private $this->dbname = $config['dbname'];
    }

    private $dbhost;
    private $dbuser;
    private $dbpass;
    private $dbname;

    public function startConn(){
        $this->DBcon = null;
        try{
            $this->DBcon = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->dbhost.";dbname=".$this->dbname, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo "error connecting:";
        }
        return $this->DBcon;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set inside constructor:

```
private $dbhost;
private $dbuser;
private $dbpass;
private $dbname;

public function __construct(){
    $config = require_once __DIR__ . 'config.php';
    $this->dbhost = $config['host'];
    $this->dbuser = $config['username'];
    $this->dbpass = $config['pass'];
    $this->dbname = $config['dbname'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you can't just return anything from your config.php file. You can only return a result inside a function. One way to implement this is to declare the array as a global variable and then use it inside all other php files that would need that configuration array.

```
<?php
/**
* Contains all configurations
*
*/
$dbconfig = array(
  'dbname' => 'user',
  'pass' => '@user.intern1',
  'username' => 'user1',
  'host' => 'localhost',
);
?>

<?php 
require_once __DIR__ . 'config.php';

class connect{
    public function __construct(){

    }

    private $dbhost = $dbconfig['host'];
    private $dbuser = $dbconfig['username'];
    private $dbpass = $dbconfig['pass'];
    private $dbname = $dbconfig['dbname'];

    public function startConn(){
        $this->DBcon = null;
        try{
            $this->DBcon = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->dbhost.";dbname=".$this->dbname, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo "error connecting:";
        }
        return $this->DBcon;
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: I thought so too. It turns out that you can return in the global scope from a require. The technique for doing this is not recommended but you can do it.

Comment: include/require do allow a return that can be assigned, as explained in the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and isn't limited to "global" scope.... `It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script which called it. Also, it's possible to return values from included files. You can take the value of the include call as you would for a normal function. `... in fact, Laravel uses this approach for its configuration files

Comment: What a great night for me to also learn something new. Thanks for sharing this :)